# Align cell so the text aligns at the bottom

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

I'd like to align the text in a TableCell to align to the bottom of the cell.  I'm not seeing this option anywhere in the tablecell properties.   Here is the snippet of code that builds that table.

```
        Table thirdTable = section.Headers.Primary.AddTable();

        thirdTable.Format.Font.Size = "7pt";

        column = thirdTable.AddColumn("1.5cm");
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;

        column = thirdTable.AddColumn("1cm");
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;

        column = thirdTable.AddColumn("7cm");
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

        column = thirdTable.AddColumn("2.5cm");
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;

        column = thirdTable.AddColumn("1cm");
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;

        column = thirdTable.AddColumn("1.5cm");
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;

        column = thirdTable.AddColumn("1.5cm");
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;

        row = thirdTable.AddRow();
        row = thirdTable.AddRow();

        row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Segment Code");
        row.Cells[1].AddParagraph("Milepoint");
        row.Cells[2].AddParagraph("Description of Milepoint");
        row.Cells[3].AddParagraph("City Name");
        row.Cells[4].AddParagraph("Segment Code");
        row.Cells[5].AddParagraph("Milepoint");
        row.Cells[6].AddParagraph("FA Route Number");
```

Answer (score 8):

Well I finally found it and it was infront of my face the entire time.  I just missed it.

It is covered in this example doc http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Invoice-sample.ashx.

This is what my code now looks like

```
        row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Segment Code");
        row.Cells[0].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        row.Cells[1].AddParagraph("Milepoint");
        row.Cells[1].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        row.Cells[2].AddParagraph("Description of Milepoint");
        row.Cells[2].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        row.Cells[3].AddParagraph("City Name");
        row.Cells[3].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        row.Cells[4].AddParagraph("Segment Code");
        row.Cells[4].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        row.Cells[5].AddParagraph("Milepoint");
        row.Cells[5].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        row.Cells[6].AddParagraph("FA Route Number");
        row.Cells[6].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add this line once:

```
row.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
```

No need to do it for each cell.